# Should I memoize Hash#dig method?

Tags: ruby, hash, memoization

My hypothesis that Hash#dig memoization should be useless memory usage, since Hash#dig should return value in constant time. (Hash#dig is a recursive C function)

So i made this little experiment with benchmark (edited mistake):

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'benchmark/ips'

class DigMemoTest
  def initialize
    @payload = {
      record: {
        id: '1',
        status: 'pending'
      },
      event: {
        at: Time.now
      }
    }
  end

  def run
    Benchmark.ips do |x|
      x.report('Hash#dig_with_memo') { dig_with_memoize }
      x.report('Hash#dig_no_memo') { dig_without_memoize }

      x.compare!
    end
  end

  def dig_without_memoize
    @payload.dig(:record, :status)
  end

  def dig_with_memoize
    return @status if defined?(@status)

    @status = @payload.dig(:record, :status)
  end
end
```

And i get result:

```
irb(main):001:0> dig_test = DigMemoTest.new
irb(main):002:0> dig_test.run

Warming up --------------------------------------
  Hash#dig_with_memo   323.224k i/100ms
    Hash#dig_no_memo   303.926k i/100ms
Calculating -------------------------------------
  Hash#dig_with_memo     12.993M (± 4.4%) i/s -     64.968M in   5.010944s
    Hash#dig_no_memo      9.630M (± 3.3%) i/s -     48.324M in   5.024331s

Comparison:
  Hash#dig_with_memo: 12992823.6 i/s
    Hash#dig_no_memo:  9630387.4 i/s - 1.35x  slower
```

Why in this case memoization improves performance, could we say that we should memoize Hash#dig?

Comment: I think your test is wrong anyway; that should be `@payload.dig(:record, :status)`, not `@payload.dig(:shipment, :status)`

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, micro-optimising something like this is pointless; I guarantee you'll have bigger fish to fry. If shaving a fraction of a microsecond off the runtime has any real value to you, then you're using the wrong language for the problem.

Comment: The term "constant" time does not mean it's literally a constant. Big O is about orders of magnitude. And even if you replaced `hash.dig` with something longer like a database query, memoizing would only help if you made the same query over and over. So, it's situational and not just a catch-all way to optimize. Memoizing will have absolutely no benefit if you call the function with different input each time.

Comment: ^^ That's actually a very good point -- How do you expect to define this "memoize" method if it takes arguments, rather than always returning one static value??! And the idea behind memoizing is to "cache expensive operations", e.g. API calls, database queries or complex calculations. Not to micro-optimise O(1) methods to shave fractions of a microsecond off the runtime.

Comment: For the argument I talk about methods which are called multiple (2+) times with same arguments. Maybe test does not clearly indicate that, but i figured it's enough to show the use-case. So my question is it worth to memoize Hash#dig, microseconds vs heap and GC

Comment: @SkomantasČepulis "called multiple times with same arguments" -- No, you called a method **with NO arguments**. My question was, how do you expect this method to work if it takes arguments? Cacheing a single static value is likely always going to put-perform a method call, but if the performance improvement is a fraction of a microsecond then it's just not worth it.

Comment: @TomLord yes, if we talk about arguments, it's not worth to talk about memoization at all. What i meant is if we have same Hash#dig in the class called multiple times. But i am totally sold on: it's not worth. We save microseconds of runtime at best and we have ripple effects on memory and GC. I take from this: memoize expensive operation, don't use it for micro-optimising.

Comment: Well, if you're really concerned about speed, your `record` would be a class/struct and not a hash inside of a hash. It's faster to do `myRecordClass.status` than `myRecordHash[:status]`. Either way, it's completely unnecessary unless you're having lag issues at this specific line in your code (extremely unlikely).